# Reset USB via batch?

Tags: windows-10, usb, batch

Occasionally something goes wrong with a USB peripheral, and I have to either reboot, or unplug then plug it back in. I want to click a batch script, or alternatively some application, and have that reset all of my USB ports.

If not batch, then some other application.

Comment: I don't think that exists or is possible from batch.

Comment: Updated to include others.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Reset a single USB port](//superuser.com/q/721302)

Comment: @LPChip See my comment :)

Comment: [How Do I Force Windows to Remove and Redetect a USB Device?](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/1D120A90884C25AF862573A700602459) - uses [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)

Comment: Devcon doesn't work. I'm on Windows 10; I don't know if that means anything. After following the guide, the root hub device status says this:

`This device is working properly.

You need to restart your computer before the changes you made to this device will take effect.`

Comment: @Lumify Try the other link I gave you ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Haha Deja-vu, in reverse. :D

Comment: The other link doesn't work either. Both of these guides literally do nothing, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 64-bit v.1903

Microsoft's devcon might be what you are looking for however it might not be worth the work.  You have to find the specific hardware or instance ID for each device which takes time.
It works in Windows XP 32-bit thru Windows 10 64-bit, it works in a batch file, it works as a shortcut, and it might not solve your problem.  It must be run with admin privileges.

To remove my Sandisk flash drive:

```
devcon64 remove "USBSTOR\DiskSanDisk_Cruzer_Blade____1.00"
```

To re-enable devices:

```
devcon64 rescan
```

To remove my multi-function printer:

```
devcon64 remove "UMB\VEN_013f&DEV_MFC-L2740DW_series"
devcon64 remove "UMB\VEN_013f&DEV_MFC-L2740DW_series"
devcon64 remove "BrotherMFC-L2740DW_sC68C"
```

You can learn more about devcon [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon).  If you don't want to install WDK, Visual Studio, or the Windows SDK you can download 64-bit devcon [here](http://originaldll.com/file/devcon64.exe/24151.html), 32-bit [here](http://originaldll.com/file/devcon.exe/26716.html).

To find the hardware or instance id use the Device Manager.

To find the hardware id of my Sandisk flash drive:
[image: device-manager]

Type `devcon64 help` for more info.

Comment: Extremely helpful! Thank you