# How to trigger the fix to "dhcp is not enabled for WiFi" from the command line?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, powershell, dhcp, wifi-configuration

Once in a while, my Wi-Fi disconnects (at home, or on the road - the network doesn't seem to be a factor). Upon running the network troubleshooter, I always get the cause of the error as:

> dhcp is not enabled for Wi-Fi.

The troubleshooter then offers to solve the issue, then it comes back and asks whether I want to run the solution as an Administrator (why wouldn't I?) and then all is well and good - until next time.

This is starting to happen more often. Not sure if it's a Windows 10 patch, or a driver issue (although I have the same issue on my other laptop, with another Wi-Fi card).

I went through all the online articles and advices: made sure all the IPv4 settings are on automatic, made sure the DHCP client service is running and on Automatic, etc..

My question is: is there a way to trigger the solution that the troubleshooter goes through from the command line/PowerShell/batch file and save myself the 2 minutes round trip of the troubleshooter going through the motions?

Comment: "This is starting to happen more often." "...I have the same issue on my other laptop, with *another* wifi card." I would personally just do a quick clean install of Windows as I suspect there is an obscure, underlying OS problem here that needs attention.

Comment: Did you try updating to the latest official driver for your wireless ?

Comment: @Overmind yes, I have. And as mentioned, it happens on more than one laptop,

Comment: @MrEthernet this is a clean install of Windows, with the latest drivers. I'm not sure which of the applications I have installed is causing DHCP to die once in a while. While trying to solve the underlying problem, my question is about alleviating the symptoms :)

Comment: The next time it stops working, open `Services.msc` and see if `DHCP client` is still running.

Comment: @MrEthernet That's the first thing I checked for - I was sure I could just `net start` it - but the service is on `automatic`, and it's running, even when the trobleshooter claims DHCP is not enabled. I wonder what other service/resource is considered DHCP...

Comment: How about this: 1) the next time it stops working, open Services and sort by Status, then count how many running services there are. 2) Then let Windows fix your network using the troubleshooter. 3) Close and re-open Services again and count how many running Services you have after DHCP is fixed. See if the number increases.

Comment: @MrEthernet didn't work - same number of services, DHCP still runinng :(

Comment: I can't see what the common factor is here. It initially seemed like a problem with the laptops but they are two different models and the problem persists even after a clean install of Windows. How did you reinstall Windows? Using the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool or something else?

Comment: Yes, the Media Creation tool. At this point, I'm starting to think it's some software I'm using that may cause it. Maybe my VPN?

Comment: The VPN application could potentially interfere with DHCP. I once had an issue with LogMeIn Hamachi where it caused an SBS 2003 server to think there was a rogue DHCP server on the network and cause it to disable its own DHCP server service - Hamachi wasn't even running on the server itself! This is a very different situation, not least because it's the DHCP *client* service (not a DHCP *server* service) but we still have VPN software and an unusual DHCP-related issue on two different model laptops, with no other obvious common factors. What VPN software are you using?

Comment: My VPN is ProXPN. Using it on Windows, iOS, Android (used it on my Mac when I was using that).

Comment: This sounds like quite an intermittent issue, which makes it harder to narrow down. I would personally remove proXPN from Laptop A for two weeks and keep in on Laptop B, then remove it from Laptop B and put it back on Laptop A. See if the problem follows the laptop that has this application installed on it. That's something you could try, enough it could be quite inconvenient to go without something you need for such a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit v.1903

Windows 10 network connection has been rock solid for me.

What you have tried, what has been suggested, I have not had to do since XP.

With the rapidly proliferating number of devices that operate in the 2.4 and 5.0 GHz frequency I am going with a failing wireless adapter and interference.

But if you want to reset your connection with a batch see my to [how to](https://superuser.com/questions/1264580/reset-usb-via-batch/1420072#1420072)
at superuser.com

My batch:

```
C:\Windows\devcon64.exe disable "USB\VID_148F&PID_3072&REV_0101"
C:\Windows\devcon64.exe enable "USB\VID_148F&PID_3072&REV_0101"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it next time. I don't think it's my router, as this happened on the road as well. Definitely something IN Windows interfering.

Comment: A congested wireless channel wouldn't specifically cause DHCP to fail in this fashion. DHCP handshakes require an absolutely *minuscule* amount of bandwidth and slow network speeds weren't mentioned as a symptom.